# How can I add a keyboard shortcut to open settings.json on vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I find myself in need of having touch the `settings.json` quite often and the manual approach is extreamly annoying as there is no directly visible link in the settings dialog.

Is there a way to create a shortcut that opens the files directly?

Comment: What is your actual usage? Open settings.json to toggle some of the setting?

Comment: which `settings.json` do you want: User, Workspace or Folder

Comment: I am interested about user level one.

Answer (score 2):

1. `Keyboard Shortcuts`: `openSettingsJson`
2. `Command Palette`: `open settings (JSON)`
3. There is a icon in the upper-right corner of settings(UI)

Answer (score 2):

The commande that you're searching is : `workbench.action.openSettingsJson` 

So to open Setting directly with a keyboard shortcut put this in your `keybindings.json` :

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+k s",
        "command": "workbench.action.openSettingsJson",
    }
```

Comment: In general, if you want a specific command, you can always search it in your `Default keybindings.json`